# Getting aktStatus in Null in terminal

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am getting the following error in my terminal if I am building the project.

aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 0
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 0
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 0
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 0
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 0
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 0
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 0
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 0
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1
aktStatus is NULL: maximum Iterations exceeded, abort 1

This should not be print in terminal

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.